# [RTABMAP, Navigation, Noetic]Error:The goal sent to the navfn planner is off the global costmap

Tags: ros, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use RTABMAP and Navigation stack.

When I specify more than 4m ahead in "2D Nav Gaol" in move_base, I get the following error message.

```
The goal sent to the navfn planner is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail to this goal.
```

I want to set a goal point at least 10m away, but the robot does not work.
The robot will go 3m away without error.

I have heard that I can fix it with the RTABMAP settings, but no matter what I look up I can't figure out how to set it up.

Below is the launch file for RTABMAP.

```
 <launch>
  <!-- Choose visualization -->
  <arg name="rtabmapviz"              default="false" /> 
  <arg name="rviz"                    default="true" />
  
  <!-- Localization-only mode -->
  <arg name="localization"            default="false"/>
  
  <!-- Corresponding config files -->
  <arg name="rtabmapviz_cfg"          default="$(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbd_gui.ini" />
  <arg name="rviz_cfg"                default="$(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/config/rgbd.rviz" />
  
  <arg name="frame_id"                default="robot_center"/>
  <arg name="odom_topic"              default="/t265/odom/sample"/>
  
  <arg name="rgbd_sync"               default="true"/>
  <arg name="approx_rgbd_sync"        default="false"/>
  <arg name="visual_odometry"         default="false"/>
  <!--<arg name="approx_sync"         default="true"/>-->
  
  <arg name="rgb_topic"               default="/d400/color/image_raw" />
  <arg name="depth_topic"             default="/d400/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw" />
  <arg name="camera_info_topic"       default="/d400/color/camera_info" />

  <param name="Mem/UseOdomGravity" type="string" value="true"/>
  <param name="Optimizer/GravitySigma" type="string" value="0.3"/>
  <param name="Vis/MaxDepth" type="string" value="3.5"/>
  
  <param name="cloud_noise_filtering_radius" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="cloud_noise_filtering_min_neighbors" value="2"/>
  <!-- param name = "proj_max_ground_height" value = "0.2" / -->
  
  <include file="$(find rtabmap_ros)/launch/rtabmap.launch">
    <arg name="rtabmapviz"              value="$(arg rtabmapviz)" /> 
    <arg name="rviz"                    value="$(arg rviz)" />
    <arg name="localization"            value="$(arg localization)"/>
    <arg name="gui_cfg"                 value="$(arg rtabmapviz_cfg)" />
    <arg name="rviz_cfg"                value="$(arg rviz_cfg)" />                                                                          

    <arg name="odom_topic"              value="$(arg odom_topic)"/>
    <arg name="frame_id"                value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
    <arg name="rgbd_sync"               value="$(arg rgbd_sync)"/>
    <arg name="depth_topic"             value="$(arg depth_topic)"/>
    <arg name="rgb_topic"               value="$(arg rgb_topic)"/>
    <arg name="camera_info_topic"       value="$(arg camera_info_topic)"/>
    <arg name="approx_rgbd_sync"        value="$(arg approx_rgbd_sync)"/>
    <arg name="visual_odometry"         value="$(arg visual_odometry)"/>   
  </include>    
</launch>
```

What should I add to which part to solve this problem?

Is it possible that it is not the RTABMAP setting in the first place, but the Navigation stack setting?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410137/%5Brtabmap,-navigation,-noetic%5Derror:the-goal-sent-to-the-navfn-planner-is-off-the-global-costmap./) by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I asked the same question in the Official RTAB-Map Forum and the great matlabbe answered it.

http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Error-The-goal-sent-to-the-navfn-planner-is-off-the-global-costmap-td9216.html#a9226

Thank you very much, Mathieu!!!

---

Originally posted by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) with karma: 13 on 2022-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0